# Not able to return expected output using python filter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on web scraping. I got heading list and now I'm filtering out unwanted thing. But while filtering I'm not getting expected output. I'm unable to find mistake in my code.

```
import re
  def filter_header(item):
    if(item):
      if(item == 'Rank & Title'):
        rank_title_split = re.split('[&]', item)
        print(rank_title_split) # getting  ['Rank','Title']
        return rank_title_split
    else:
        print(item) 
        return item


 imdb_header_list = [False, 'Rank & Title', 'IMDb Rating', 'Your Rating',   False]
 imdb_filtered_header_list =  filter(filter_header,imdb_header_list)
 print(list(imdb_filtered_header_list))
```

Getting output=

```
['Rank & Title', 'IMDb Rating', 'Your Rating']
```

My expected output =

```
[['Rank','Title'],'IMDb Rating', 'Your Rating']
```

Comment: You are not using the filter() method correctly.  The first argument of this method has to be a function that returns a boolean value (True or False), not the actual item.  Review Python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter

Comment: Thanks AlexK, Its really a huge mistake from my side. instead of using as filter I was using it some what like map function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For parsing `'Rank & Title'`, a filter is not needed. You can just apply `filter_header` to each item in the list:

```
imdb_filtered_header_list =  [filter_header(item) for item in imdb_header_list]
```

Then you can filter out False values.

Working implementation:

```
import re
def filter_header(item):
    if(item == 'Rank & Title'):
        rank_title_split = re.split('[&]', item)
        return rank_title_split
    return item


imdb_header_list = [False, 'Rank & Title', 'IMDb Rating', 'Your Rating',   False]
imdb_filtered_header_list =  [filter_header(item) for item in imdb_header_list]
imdb_filtered_header_list = list(filter(bool, imdb_filtered_header_list))  # remove False values
print(imdb_filtered_header_list)
```

Output:

```
[['Rank ', ' Title'], 'IMDb Rating', 'Your Rating']
```

Comment: Thanks, Its working fine . I was also  not aware of  "filter(bool, imdb_filtered_header_list)".

Answer (score 1):

Filter function definition says

```
The filter() function returns an iterator were the items are filtered through a function to test if the item is accepted or not.
```

What you are looking for is an iterator and not filter